# How do I use lag function in sql to display dates < sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

If I want to display all the dates from dual which is less than **sysdate** using lag condition ,how do I do that

select sysdate from  Items-how do I use lag in this query?

My output should display all the dates less than **sysdate** using lag condition

```
Date
30-jun-2015
29-june-2015
28-june-2015
```

etc

Comment: `dual` has one row, so `lag()` doesn't really make sense.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Perhaps you meant you wanted to generate a list of dates, starting with today and going back X number of days? In which case, you would use connect by. E.g. `select trunc(sysdate) - level dt from dual connect by level <= 10;`

Comment: @Gayathri . . . Your question is still unclear.  There are *a lot* of dates less than `sydate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1 - Selecting dates from start date to today**:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL + 1 AS "Date"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL + 1 >= DATE '2015-06-26'
```

**Results**:

```
|                   Date |
|------------------------|
| July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 31 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 28 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2 - Selecting dates between multiple ranges**:

```
WITH ranges ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2015-06-02', DATE '2015-06-07' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2015-06-12', DATE '2015-06-14' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT START_DATE + COLUMN_VALUE AS "Date"
FROM   ranges,
       TABLE( CAST ( MULTISET(
         SELECT LEVEL - 1
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 <= END_DATE
       ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST ) )
```

**Results**:

```
|                   Date |
|------------------------|
| June, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 05 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 06 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 07 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 12 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 13 2015 00:00:00 |
| June, 14 2015 00:00:00 |
```